# Workaround for AssociationTypeMismatch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring, associations

I'm in the middle of a refactoring, where I have written new models for new incoming data that will be behind a feature flag, while simultaneously keeping old models active for incoming data for people who don't yet have the feature flag. The old and new models both interact with the same table in the database.

i.e.

```
class Poem < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to: :author
   belongs_to: :anthology, optional: true
end

class Anthology < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to: :author
   has_many: :poems
end

class Author < ApplicationRecord
   has_many: :anthologies
   has_many: :poems
end


class NewPoem < ApplicationRecord
   self.table_name = 'poems'

   belongs_to: :author, class_name: 'NewAuthor'
   belongs_to: :anthology, class_name: 'NewAnthology', optional: true
end

class NewAnthology < ApplicationRecord
   self.table_name = 'anthologies'

   belongs_to: :author, class_name: 'NewAuthor'
   has_many: :poems, class_name: 'NewPoem'
end

class NewAuthor < ApplicationRecord
   self.table_name = 'authors'
   has_many: :anthologies, class_name: 'NewAnthology'
   has_many: :poems, class_name: 'NewPoem'
end
```

When I have new books being created, I want to assign the new book to the author

```
anthology = Anthology.find(1)
@poem = NewPoem.new
@poem.author = anthology.author
```

Which gives me an error

`ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (NewAuthor(#70008442274840) expected, got Author(#47031421032620)):`

Is there any way to get around this? or will I not be able to associate the models to the old models without a data migration?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to change the first line that fetches the `Anthology` record. Currently, it fetches a record of the `Anthology` model as `anthology = Anthology.find(1)`. However, this model refers to the old `Author` model. 
In the next line, `@poem = NewPoem.new` instantiates an object of the `NewPoem` model, and the next line tries to assign an author to it. However, `@poem.author` would be an object of the class `NewAuthor`, but it is being given a value as `@poem.author = anthology.author`, where `anthology.author` still refers to the old `Author` table.
Changing the first line to `anthology = NewAnthology.find(1)` would fix the issue. It would fetch the same record as `Anthology.find(1)` since they query on the same table.
Overall code then becomes:

```
anthology = NewAnthology.find(1)
@poem = NewPoem.new
@poem.author = anthology.author
```

Comment: oh ok, I see. so if the new model was defined in that way, calling NewAnthology.find(1) would still give you the same table entry. that makes sense now that you say it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the new models are just supersets of the old ones. You could define `NewPoem` (and the rest of new models) as:

```rb
class NewPoem < Poem
  validates :new_colums

  def new_cool_stuff
  end
end
```

That way you can avoid to redefine associations.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord actually has a built in Single Table Inheritance mechanism that you can use here.

Start by adding a column named `type` to the table:

```
class AddTypeToPoems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :poems, :type, :string
    add_index :poems, :type
  end
end
```

Then set the classes to inherit:

```
class Poem < ApplicationRecord
end

class NewPoem < Poem
  # gets its table name from the parent class
end
```

ActiveRecord automatically sets the `type` column and even uses it when retrieving records:

```
irb(main):001:0> NewPoem.create
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  NewPoem Create (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "poems" ("created_at", "updated_at", "type") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2019-05-08 19:17:45.086947"], ["updated_at", "2019-05-08 19:17:45.086947"], ["type", "NewPoem"]]
   (0.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<NewPoem id: 1, title: nil, created_at: "2019-05-08 19:17:45", updated_at: "2019-05-08 19:17:45", type: "NewPoem">
irb(main):002:0> Poem.first
  Poem Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "poems".* FROM "poems" ORDER BY "poems"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<NewPoem id: 1, title: nil, created_at: "2019-05-08 19:17:45", updated_at: "2019-05-08 19:17:45", type: "NewPoem">
irb(main):003:0>
```

So even if we use `Poem.first` it instanciates a `NewPoem` instance from the result. If you use the finders on the subclasses rails will automatically scope it:

```
irb(main):003:0> NewPoem.all
  NewPoem Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "poems".* FROM "poems" WHERE "poems"."type" IN ('NewPoem') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

If you only want the "old" type you need to use:

```
Poem.where(type: [nil, 'Poem'])
```